# External HDMI monitor does not work via USB 3.0 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c

**;tldr**

ThinkPad X240 USB 3.0 port > USB-C adapter > USB-C dock's HDMI output > HDMI cable > external HDMI monitor = the monitor is not detected

---

I need to connect my older ThinkPad X240 to an external HDMI monitor. Unfortunately, the X240 does not have an HDMI output. With my other notebok, which has a USB-C port, I am able to connect to that external monitor via a Fitfort USB-C dock with an HDMI output. Unfortunately, the X240 does not even have a USB-C port. So I bought a Vention USB 3.0 to USB-C adapter for connecting the dock. The USB hub of the dock seems to be working well, unfortunately, the display is not detected.

I tried installing Synaptics Display Link driver as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379081/1044065), but it still does not work. Any ideas where to even begin to debug this? Thx

Comment: The adapter may not support the signals the monitor needs. Not all of this type of adapter work. What kernel are you running?

Comment: USB-C cables can carry display data from the GPU.  USB-A cannot.  Your setup does not.   You should get a VGA->HDMI converter instead.

Comment: It has a mini DisplayPort, use a DP-HDMI adapter. **The contraption you're using does not and cannot work.** You can't convert a USB3.0 into a USB-C (3.2) with video capabilities. Not all USB-C ports support it and NO USB-A supports it. Video over USB-C has nothing to do with DisplayLink. You're confusing lots of different things/technologies here, USB-C docks with video outputs  are NOT DisplayLink. DisplayLink is a proprietary chip that emulates an external video output over traditional USB, even USB2.0 (mileage varies).

Comment: Thanks you all for your comments. I am capable of connecting my monitor through other means of course. I just wanted to have the convenience of plugging just one connector to connect all devices at once using the usb-c dock which I already have. So the issue is just that you can not convert USB3.0 to USB-C with video capabilities? Because USB 3.0 to HDMI adapters exist. If somebody is willing to summarize this in an answer I would be happy to accept it.